# jQuery Store Locator Plugin letter on list

Tags: jquery, plugins

I want to change the letters in the list with numbers.

I use [this plugin](http://www.bjornblog.com/web/jquery-store-locator-plugin/comment-page-4), is it possible?

I tried to change this code but doesn't work

```
// Letter markers image
                letterMarkerImg = {
                    url: 'https://mt.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-waypoint-b.png&text=' + letter + '&psize=16&font=fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf&color=ff333333&ax=44&ay=48'
                };

                // Letter markers
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position : point,
                    map      : map,
                    icon     : letterMarkerImg,
                    draggable: false
                });
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Well so from where are you setting `letter` variable???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be no possible because the first letter of the list "A" is written directly in the [code](https://github.com/bjorn2404/jQuery-Store-Locator-Plugin/blob/master/src/js/jquery.storelocator.js#L968).

Maybe you should open them an [issue](https://github.com/bjorn2404/jQuery-Store-Locator-Plugin/issues) and explain your need, or fork the project and implement this feature on your own :) .

Comment: in those lines, i change the letter "A" with "1"